# Bean Validation transforms Object RequestParam into @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation, spring-restcontroller

I have the following:

```
 @PostMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> getLoginStatus(@Valid LoginRequest loginRequest){
        //some stuff here
 }
```

The `loginRequest` paramater is a `@RequestParam`, but, because it is a custom object, the `@RequestParam` annotation in front of the object is not needed. The problem is that when any bean-validation annotation is put in front of the custom object, the object is transformed into a body parameter(`@RequestBody`), but we want to validate the object as request param, not body param.

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Have you already looked into the @Validated annotation in Spring? [Here](https://sdqali.in/blog/2015/12/04/validating-requestparams-and-pathvariables-in-spring-mvc/) is an example.

Comment: The fact that it is a custom object has nothing to do with the fact that you have (or not) to add the `@RequestParam` annotation. What now happens is spring creates an instance of the class and does some binding(most of what is the same as with `@ModelAttribute`).. If you would use `@RequestParam` it would try yo convert the request parameter to the given `LoginRequest` object using a `Converter` or custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. Basically your understanding of what happens is off.

Comment: I don't understand. Juste use Valid @ModelAttribute LoginForm loginForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the `LoginRequest` attributes became part of the `RequestBody`, and not of `RequestParameters` anymore, is due to `springfox-swagger` version 2.6.1. Upgrading to version 2.7.0 fixed this issue for us.